# Save Dialog window shows up multiple times after completing export

Tags: c#, wpf

I am seeing an issue where the Save Dialog box is being displayed again to the user after the export to excel is complete and we ask the user if they want to view the file or not.

If they select YES OR NO, the Save Dialog window pops up again. If you hit save, the code is not even ran again.

Has anyone seen anything similar to this on a windows computer?

Just trying to see if anyone runs across the post to see if they have seen something similar. The break point in the code is not hitting twice when the Save Dialog window comes up again.

```
                            if (WinUIMessageBox.Show("Would you like to view the exported file?", "Open File", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
                        {
                            // open the exported document
                            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(SaveFileDialogService.GetFullFileName());
                            Process.Start(startInfo);
                        }
```

Comment: The code you've shown wouldn't cause that. Can you edit to include a [mcve] that does? Chances are it's something to do with the event handler that code is part of or such, but hard to say with certainty without context.

Comment: Okay. I'll try to post tomorrow.

Comment: At least show us your SaveFileDialogService code. That is what is displaying the dialog I assume so that is where the issue probably is. What you've shown so far isn't the problem.